# postgresql 9.3 In the django 1.6

Tags: python-3.x, django-models, postgresql-9.3

error to set postgresql9.3 in the Django1.6.

I have installed postgresql, psycopg2 and Django.

my code :
settings.py :

```
 DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.psycopg3'),
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'root',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '5432',
         }
   }
```

and to python manage.py shell :

```
from django.db import connection
cursor = connection.cursor()
```

Errors :

```
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "root"
```

Please help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The database name in your settings.py should be modified. Actually you had entered the format used for sqlite db. For postgres, it should be

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'NAME': 'dbname',
    'USER': 'root',
    'PASSWORD': 'rootXXX',
    'HOST': '',
    'PORT': '',
}
}
```

Create the Database 'dbname' in your postgres before synchronizing it with your app